# Echo a <input> and use variable as name

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

I have some problem with my code. I want to insert the variable $columnnames as the name for the checkbox. I have tried several things but no one successful.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host", "user", "password") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("database")or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "select * from table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numcolumn = mysql_num_fields($result);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $numcolumn; $i++ ) { $columnnames = mysql_field_name($result, $i);

echo "<input type='checkbox' name='".$columnnames."' value='yes'>" .str_replace('_', ' ', $columnnames)."\n";
}
?>
```

When I run the code, it looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="1">
```

With a empty name?

Comment: Please avoid using the _deprecated_ mysql functions and move to either `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: _I want to insert the variable $columnnames as the name for the checkbox_. It's working fine.

Comment: What result you get whit your code?

Comment: Table is a reserved word in MySQL, suggest you rename it to something else or escape it with backticks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about "some problem" and "several thing" making this question impossible to answer because there is no problem description or information about your research / attempts.

Comment: `mysql_connect("host", "user", "password")` I am sure those aren't your real credentials?

Comment: When I run the code, it looks like this <input type="checkbox" name="" value="yes">. With a empty name?

Comment: @A.Sejersen check the answer below and comment on it if the desired result is any different?

Comment: That can't be your actual output. You are using single quotes for the attributes and the value is `yes` in the PHP.

Comment: I posted a answer for you below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If everything else works fine (your database connection, query, results etc) along with a proper `<form>` tag.

This is an example to demonstrate that it works:

```
<?php
$columnnames = "Hawas_Ka_Pujaari";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='".$columnnames."' value='yes'>" .str_replace('_', ' ', $columnnames)."\n";
?>
```

[image: Since I could not find any PHP/HTML online compiler]

**EDIT:**

After giving it a couple of reads, these are the things you should check/dry debug (or in our language: *Desi Debugging*)

**1)** `echo $result = mysql_query($query);` and see what you get? because it's most likely that the query is failing (without giving you any error since you do not have error reporting enable and still using the *deprecated* mysql fucntions which will no longer be supported).

**2)** `mysql_field_name();` return the name of a field in a recordset So if the query fails in the first place, this > `$columnnames = mysql_field_name($result, $i);` is of no use. (Again the *deprecated* mysql functions)

> Note: Considering the fact that you have a successful connection and
>   not literally like `mysql_connect("host", "user", "password")` along
>   with the proper valid table selected, Oh `table` is a reserved word in MySQL
>   like [Robbie Averill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2812842/robbie-averill) mentioned in the comments so you should consider changing
>   that as well. And the fact that the query is successful, it should
>   work.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="" value="yes">
"A Sejersen"
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="yes">
"B Sejersen"

This is copied from developer tool in Google Chrome. As you can see it is fine echo the $columnname. But the name is empty.

Comment: @A.Sejersen that indicates the failure to fetch the `$columnnames` I suppose. What values do you have in your table column?

Comment: There isn't any row in the table rigth now.
Column 1 is called A_Sejersen.
Column 2 is called B_Sejersen.
I try to get the name to be the same as the one which is printed.

Comment: @A.Sejersen Ahh, I see. `echo "ColNames: " . $columnnames = mysql_field_name($result, $i);` and what do you see?

Comment: ColNames: A_SejersenColNames: B_Sejersen

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I tried to run it on a wordpress page, which is for some reason did not work. But when I uploaded it directly to the webserver it worked. Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 2):

You may try this.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $key . "' value='" . $value . "'>" . str_replace('_', ' ', $key) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: While this may work but please do not demonstrate/promote the _deprecated_ mysql functions. An example using either `mysqli` or `PDO` would be encouraging. Ps. it needs a fix.

Comment: In my personal use, I prefer PDO, but as he's done with mysql, so I had to do that.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari you did the same in your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use in this way

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host","username","pass") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("dbname")or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "select * from tablename";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $row_name= $row['row_name'];

  $row_name= htmlspecialchars($row['row_name'],ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='";
echo $row_name;
echo "'/>";
echo $row_name;
echo"<br>";
}
?>
```